# Change css class of a component by onClick on Icon in React using useState hook

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-hooks

I am new to React and I was hoping someone could help me with this issue. I am trying to render some images called 'cards' from an array based on the same data I've received from Axios. I basically need to render an array of card props which have an `<i>` tag with some font-awesome class attached to them. When I click on the "fa-search-plus" font-awesome icon, I want the parent of this icon `<div>` to trigger the `onClick` such that the css property of the sibling `<img>` of this `<div>` can be changed. For some reason with the following code, this does not seem to happen. Any fix is appreciated. Thanks!

```
const GameCards = (cards) => {

  const [cardimgclass, setCardimgclass] = useState(true);

  const onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCardimgclass(!cardimgclass);
  };

  const loadCardsByCategory = (cards) => {
    var allCards = [];
    if (cards)
      cards.forEach((item, i) => {
        allCards.push(
          <div key={item._id} className="card-container">
            <img
              className={cardimgclass ? "card-reg" : "card-big"}
              src={item.src}
              alt="No file"
            />
            <div onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}>
              {" "}
              <i className="fas fa-search-plus"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    return allCards;
  };

  const loadCards = (cards) => {
  return (
      <Fragment>
         <div className="cardgallery">{loadCardsByCategory(cards)}</div>
      </Fragment>      
 )
};

  const loadCardsUsingMemo = useMemo(() => loadCards(cards), [cards]);
  return  <Fragment>{loadCardsUsingMemo}</Fragment>;
};
```

Comment: I think you should change a bit your logic
First at all, if you click on any search icon, all you images will get class `card-big`

In fact you should set to state image index

`const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(-1);`

and now in code: `className={i ===  imageIndex ? "card-reg" : "card-big"}`

and last peace pass index to your on click function <div onClick={(e) => onClick(e, i)}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your primary problem is that you are not destructuring your props object:

`const GameCards = cards => {`

You need to change that to:

`const GameCards = ({ cards }) => {`

Also, remove the `useMemo` stuff.  It is not helping you here.  Here is a [slimmed down version](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-surf-mo0l3?file=/src/App.js) of your code.  I'm changing the `background-color` property with the class, but the concept is the same.  Hope that helps!

EDIT: Also note, as in the example your logic is currently changing *all* of the elements.  If you want to only modify the class for one element you could use the method of passing the index (or better yet, the ID!).  Here is an example:

```
const [cardimgclass, setCardimgclass] = useState();

...

const onClick = (e, item) => setCardimgclass(item._id)

...

<div onClick={e => onClick(e, item)} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your  help guys. I used both of your suggestions as references and created my own solution by passing the image._id which is unique in the react database. I also made use of useRef() to get the previous value so now my click acts as a toggle. Onclick every odd number of times sets css to card-big and even times to card-reg. My need for the project also changed midway. I am now clicking on the image itself and not the icon. I click toggle on the image as my css causes image to become big, thus hiding the icon. This is great https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-carson-fgk9x?file=/src/App.js